# Send a Java Hashmap to JSNI (Javascript)

Tags: java, gwt

I am calling a jsni method and trying to send my java hashmap

something like this

```
       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
       map.put("Test", "123");
       map.put("Test2", "234");

       call(map);
```

}

```
        public static native void call(HashMap<String, String> map) /*-{
        alert(map);
        var empMap = map; 
        var s = empMap['Test'];

        }-*/;
```

Here i want to read the contents inside my Hashmap in my javascript code, but it gives "undefined" in var s. null error.

please guide how can i acheive this i.e to get the contents of this java hashmap inside my javascript code.

Comment: Have you tried to first convert the `HashMap` into `JSON` string and then parsing the `JSON` as `Object` to use in your `JavaScript` code?

Comment: as i am in client side ,can only use com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject, which is accepting a jsonvalue and not taking my hashMap in it

Comment: if i do this in my javascript code :   var eMap = map; 
  alert(eMap);, it displays all vales in my hashmap correctly , but now i just need to get a specific valuw , like   eMap[Test];

Answer (score 1):

Try to do:

```
public static native void call(HashMap<String, String> map) /*-{
        alert(map);
        var empMap = map; 
        var s = empMap.@java.util.HashMap::get(Ljava/lang/Object;)('Test');
}-*/;
```

inside your JSNI call.